# Disabling keyboard echoing in input text fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, linux

Scenario:
I have a system that send data through json/websocket to a webpage, that page receives such data and update related fields.

Example to explain how it works:
- Page is loaded and focus is in an input text field (cursor is blinking on it), 
- User presses some key that, through a back-end app, is captured directly from the serial port, do something with it, create a json including the captured data and send it to the web page (websocket)
- java script gets the data and populate the related field.

I'm looking for a way to disable any echoing from keyboard, and keep only page updated with the data that comes from the backend.

Read-only fields are not a option cause I need the blinking cursor showing up in the field being used.

Suggestion to block it on html/js/css, in the browser or even on Linux SO will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I easily solve my issue using JQuery!

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on("keypress", function (event) {
   if (event.which !== 0) {
      console.log('blocking keypress event');
      event.preventDefault();
   }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label>Name: </label><input type="text" id="bef">
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Now only data that comes from backend populates fields on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but wouldn't you want the user to see their keystrokes (get confirmation) as they are typed (think entering passwords where you see the letter briefly before it is converted to an *).  Then, your backend server can just automatically over-write the text box as you go (a character at a time).  Or just add a method (on-change?) to send a backspace to the input box a fraction of a second after any key entry (but don't capture it on the serial port).

Comment: PGilm, the way data gets on the page is already working like this, I meant, keyboard, serial port capture, back-end and then, through websocket/json, data is sent to html. I had a different front-end, where I didn't need to worry about keyboard echoing. But since I changed it to html it starts to be an issue.